# Devise redirect back on sign up failure with validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a simple Devise registration form with the `validatable` plugin. It mostly works as intended, if the user forgets to enter a first name it redirects them back with a red validation message.

The problem is it redirects to the same path a successful login would have the user go to (i.e. it redirects them to `/user` and not back to `/user/sign_up`). If the user then refreshes the page for whatever reason they get a `No route matches [GET] "/user"` error.

How can I force a redirect to go back to the original `/user/sign_up` route on a sign up failure? I know I can hack the `create` action in the registration controller but when I redirect to the proper route I lose the Devise validation messages.

---

*Update*

It appears the problem is the way Devise handles `respond_with` [Rails 4 How Overwrite Devise Respond Path Upon Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19574643/772309). It looks like Devise tries to render a `create` template at /user but I still can't override it.

Comment: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/4573

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you can create devise controllers using following command -

```
rails generate devise:controllers users
```

Then you have to modify your routes for devise

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users,
         :skip => [:registrations]

  devise_scope :user do
    get "user/sign_up", to: "users/registrations#new", as: :new_user_registration
    post "user/sign_up", to: "users/registrations#create", as: :user_registration
  end

end
```

Hope it's work.

Comment: Is there a better way to have it work with Devise than circumventing the Devise controller? Im now getting a `undefined method `validatable?' for nil:NilClass` error on a method in the Devise controller.

Comment: I can't understand what's problem in your code. Can you give me you code repository link or gist of controller, model and routes code and i can see the code. Also i checked above routes code to my local machine and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks, that did work actually. I still don't know why this hack is necessary and why it wouldn't be the default for Devise `registrations` controller. Maybe I deviated from the Devise best practice somewhere else? Either way thank you!

Comment: Works for me, Thanks!